# How do I define an Eclipse "Code Style" for a C++ Macro?

Tags: eclipse, coding-style

When I auto-format my C++ code containing a macro, Eclipse adds a line break and indentation before the ";". For example:

```
// Tests
TEST(Test1, Test1)
{
    EXPECT_EQ (2.0*2.0, 4.0)
        ;
}
```

How do I define/edit the Code Style so that it would instead be shown as:

```
// Tests
TEST(Test1, Test1)
{
    EXPECT_EQ (2.0*2.0, 4.0);
}
```

Comment: That's super weird. Did you ever find the solution? If so, post it here to help the next person.